# Using enums for keys in an object in order to reuse in mutation

Tags: typescript, enums

What is the best way to store the keys of an object and their types so that the keys can be used as a value and not just a type?
I would like to check an attribute string against the enum within a mutation function so the type of the value can be checked against the expected type.

When using enums to declare keys and then name the enum's types, TS doesn't seems to be checking if a value is within an enum or not correctly.

[Example code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-mutation-enum-question-zp7bv8?file=/src/index.ts)

```
export enum CellKeyStrings {
  CHARACTER = "character",
  PATH_TO_BOARD = "pathToBoardId"
}
export enum CellKeyBooleans {
  IS_PASSABLE = "isPassable"
}
export enum CellKeyReadOnly {
  ID = "id"
}

type PartialRecord<K extends string, T> = {
  [P in K]?: T;
};

type ReadOnlyRecord<K extends string, T> = {
  readonly [P in K]: T;
};

type CellStringProperties = PartialRecord<CellKeyStrings, string>;
type CellBooleanProperties = PartialRecord<CellKeyBooleans, boolean>;
type CellReadOnlyProperties = ReadOnlyRecord<CellKeyReadOnly, string>;

export interface Cell
  extends CellStringProperties,
    CellBooleanProperties,
    CellReadOnlyProperties {}

interface MutationFunctionProps {
  cellId: string;
  attribute: keyof Cell;
  value: string | boolean;
}
const cells: Cell[] = [{ id: "A-1" }];

const mutationFunction = ({
  cellId,
  attribute,
  value
}: MutationFunctionProps) => {
  const selectedCell = cells.find(({ id }) => id === cellId);

  if (!selectedCell) {
    throw Error("cannot find cell");
  }

  if (
    Object.keys(CellKeyBooleans).includes(attribute) &&
    !Object.keys(CellKeyReadOnly).includes(attribute)
  ) {
    if (typeof value !== "boolean") {
      throw Error("incorrect value type for attribute");
    }
    selectedCell[attribute] = value;
  }
};
```

Comment: Can you explain how the code example pertains to your question?  What specifically is going wrong with the code?  I see [an error](https://tsplay.dev/WYvb2w) (can't write to a readonly property) but that doesn't seem to be what you're asking about.  Could you ensure that the code here makes a [mre] which clearly demonstrates the issue you're facing and does not have any unrelated problems?

Comment: sure, here is a [working simplest version of the mutation function](https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-mutation-enum-question-forked-dgnmbg)
What i would like to do is reuse the information in the type declarations in the mutation so that there is less repetition make sense?

Comment: So is this just a code review question? Nothing is wrong with your code but you want to do something better?  You can always use the enum as a type instead of `string` like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m351yw) maybe, but I'm still not sure I understand what your actual issue is.   For a [mre] it really helps if the problem jumps out at you (an error, an obvious comment) instead of having to read each line carefully.  Note that once you do have a [mre] it should be in plaintext form in the question itself.